# How to change width of an input field using bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I tried several things to increase the field for email displayed. As you can see, it's chopped off and it would look better if the field was longer.

[image: EmailFieldChopsEmailAddress]

The code behind it looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="HomeZipCode">Home Zip Code:</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="EmailAddress">Email Address </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
  </div>    
</div>
```

I've tried changing `col-md-4` of the div to `col-md-5` or 6 for the div, I've tried changing `col-xs-5` to a bigger number as well.

I don't think I need to change `col-md-4` to a bigger number for the label.

Any ideas why no changes are showing to make the email field wider? There's plenty of room on the page.

I looked at [bootstrap examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/) and it looks like what I tried should have worked.

How do I get the email address field to be wider?

***Update***
Per suggest answer of @JustLearning, I tried this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="HomeZipCode">Home Zip Code:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="EmailAddress">Email Address </label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up adding this to site.css:

```
#step1Edit #EmailAddress{
    width:23em;
}
```

Then in my RegistrationStep1.cshtml, I added this in the outer div:

```
<div class="form-horizontal" id="step1Edit">
```

And that worked with the email identifier, with no changes:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="EmailAddress">Email Address </label>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-auto col-lg-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Basically, my answer :)

Comment: Not really...  I didn't use width 100%. I'm not sure what that would do.  And I added the reference to the css in the form class, but you added it in the @html.EditorFor part.

Comment: I meant applying a width to the input itself versus adjusting the bootstrap grid container. Also, your technique is going to require a site.css entry for every control with the issue. Glad you got it working though.

Answer (score 1):

`Col-xs-5` is applied to extra small screens only

So what you can do is chain the other screen class E.g:

`col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5` this will take care of all screen sizes.

Further more, you can reduce you `col-xs-5` for the homezip to 
`col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4`

and increase you email div to

`col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8`

Use the above approach to figure out what the grid should look like. Also apply the above approach in the child grid i.e:

```
    <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="EmailAddress">Email Address </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
```

Example of bootstrap grid using `col-md` classes:

[image]

Another thing you can try is input sizing: add class `input-sm` to you input elements to make them smaller and fit in more text

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  See my update above.  It didn't seem to work.

Comment: what screen size are you running you running your tests on? as i mentioned col-xs is for extra small screen i.e. mobile. If you see your issue in desktop or table screen size then col-xs is the wrong class to use

Comment: It's just a regular computer monitor.  I updated the div for the email to <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">. See Update in my original question.  It's still not showing wider for the email field.

Comment: first increase your parent div class ie. <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5"> to something like col-xs-8 col-sm-8 etc, So then your email label and input have more screen scace in the second half of he screen, If that does not help setup a jsfiddle and i will take a look. Just remember each row has 12 cells so so your the sum of col-whatever of the two main divs cannot be greater than 12. The same applies for all other bootstrap rows when you are using col-whatever

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I do for Kendo controls:

First create a css class to set width at 100%:

```
.width100 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then add it to the control:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, 
    new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control width100", @required = "required" } })
```

Answer (score 1):

Added the width to 100% will resolve that issue as below ...

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="HomeZipCode">Home Zip Code:</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @style="width:100%" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HomeZipCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-lg-5">
            <label class="control-label col-md-4 required" for="EmailAddress">Email Address </label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @required = "required", @style="width:100%" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```